# Is there a way to set up an alert when someone is added to the SharePoint group?

Tags: list, permissions, alert

"Person A" is the access provisioner of the SharePoint site, but "Person B" is the manager and wants to get alerts of who is given access to the site. Are you able to set an alert for this scenario?

I am trying to look through the settings to see if I can set an alert, but only for changes within a list.

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using ? 2013 , 2016 or SP Online ?

Comment: I want to say 2013, but is there a way I can tell for sure besides looking at the GUI/interface?

Comment: when you go to the settings page , does it go to `siteurl/_layouts/15/settings.aspx` or `siteurl/_layouts/settings.aspx` ?

Comment: it goes to `siteurl/_layouts/15/settings.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 introduced a new event receiver class called *SPSecurityEventReceiver*

Just like the normal event receiver, **SPSecurityEventReceiver** has the **GroupUserAdded** method which can be overridden and we can write our custom logic to send email to the group manager whenever a new user is added. You can refer to the below article that explains how to trigger the Event Receiver when a user is added to the group.

[Event Receiver that triggers on User addition to Group](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/create-groupuseradded-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)

```
    publicoverridevoid GroupUserAdded(SPSecurityEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.GroupUserAdded(properties);

        // Get the added user details
        SPUser userAdded = 
        properties.Web.AllUsers.GetByID(properties.GroupUserId);

        // Get the group details to which the user is added
        SPGroup groupAdded = properties.Web.Groups.GetByID(properties.GroupId);

       // Add logic to send mail to the respective user
    }
```

[How to send email using SPUtility](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/1263/sending-email-from-sharepoint-using-server-side-object-model.aspx)